# Using dot-notation to access Immutable.js Records

Tags: record, immutable.js

I read [here](https://tonyhb.gitbooks.io/redux-without-profanity/content/using_immutablejs_records.html) that is possible to access a prop of a Record object using dot-notation like **person.Name** X **person.get('name')**. However it isn't working to me if I try to access it using the property directly.

My code:

```
new Record({
  id: 123,
  description: 'Foo',
  imgSrc: 'https://foo.co'
}))
```

If I try to access the property **description** directly like **person.description** it doesn't work. I should use **person.get('description')** rather access it directly.

What I'm doing wrong since it should let me access the property directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're a using a Map, but property access using dot notation is only available on Immutable.Record. Here's the relevant section on the site: https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Record

```
//first make a template
var MyThingie = Record({id:123, description:'Foo', imgSrc: 'https://foo.co'});
//now create records
var myRecord = new MyThingie({description:'Not the default description'});
//outputs 'Not the default description'
console.log(myRecord.description);
```

Comment: Yeap. That has worked to me. I didn't about the template needed